# Interpolation with scipy's SmoothSphereBivariateSpline

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I want to use [scipy.interpolate.SmoothSphereBivariateSpline](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.SmoothSphereBivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.SmoothSphereBivariateSpline)
 to interpolate temperature on a map (I'm not familiar with data interpolation, so this maybe not a good choice but I'd like to give it a go).

These are what I did:

- Load data from a tsv file, which looks like this:

> latitude  longitude   temperature city
>
> 30.22 120.14  39  2caves
>
> 30.26 120.13  39  3caves
>
> 30.23 120.13  39  Anlong
>
> 33.48 108.5   30  Anda
>
> 37.2  100.74  15  Anan
>
> ...

- into pandas

  ```
  data = pandas.read_table('temp.tsv')
  ```
- Get radians from lat, lon:

  ```
  theta = numpy.array(data.latitude) / 180 * numpy.pi # the lat, lon domain is safe here so
  phi = numpy.array(data.longitude) / 180 * numpy.pi  # I won't adjust for the output range
  temp = numpy.array(data.temperature)
  ```
- Feed them into scipy:

  ```
  lut = SmoothSphereBivariateSpline(theta, phi, temps)
  ```

Then the function throws a ValueError:

> ValueError: 
>   The required storage space exceeds the available storage space: nxest
>   or nyest too small, or s too small.
>   The weighted least-squares spline corresponds to the current set of
>   knots.

I've tried to adjust the s parameter with different values, from 1, 2, 3 to 7000, 8000, it just kept being too small. What should I do to make the interpolation work?

Comment: I faced the same problem of spherical interpolation and haven't been able to make this class work... exact same issue

Answer (score 1):

Just for the records: following [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.SmoothSphereBivariateSpline.html) there is a smoothing parameter `s` to be chosen; the default value is `s=0`, but sometimes it is critical to select it manually as suggested in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I tried an alternative method that worked. `RectSphereBivariateSpline` from the same library. It took `u,v` or `theta, phi grid` and interpolate it from the grid.

It seems your data sample also falls on a grid, this should work for you too!

Note that the north pole and south pole need some special treatment in this function.

https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectSphereBivariateSpline.html

I tried with a few examples and it seems the problem `SmoothSphereBivariateSpline` faces is the memory scaling. So if we have too many points on our grid it will memory overflow. This seems to be a more flexible method suitable for points irregularly dropped on sphere instead of regular grid like ours.